# Is it possible to send email using Fuel SDK for Java?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, fuel-sdk, java

I'm facing the problem with Fuel SDK integration with Java - I can't understand how to send the newly created email.

In [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1api.meta/salesforce1api/exacttarget_dev_build_app.htm) I see how to perform similar operation using Php:

```
$response = new ET_Post($myclient, 'Send', array("List"=> array("ID" => "YOUR_LIST_ID_GOES_HERE"), "Email" => array("CustomerKey" => "123")));
```

But I don't see similar object `ET_Post` in [Java SDK](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/FuelSDK-Java/). How can I trigger the email sending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example of doing a User-Initiated Send on this page: [**Creating a Send Object**](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/creating-a-send-object.html)

Here's a snip from the Java section:

```
public void testSendEmailToList() throws RemoteException {

    Soap stub = init();
    Send send = new Send();
    send.setEmail(testGetEmailById());
    List l1= new List();
    l1.setID(new Integer(12345));
    List l2= new List();
    l2.setID(new Integer(54321));
    List[] ids = {l1,l2};
    send.setList(ids);

    send.setFromAddress("acruz@example.com");
    send.setFromName("Angel Cruz");

    APIObject[] apiObjectList = {send};
    CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest(new CreateOptions(), apiObjectList);
    CreateResponse createResponse = stub.create(createRequest);
    System.out.println("CreateResponse ::: " + createResponse.getOverallStatus());

}
```

Comment: ok, thanks, but as far as I see, it's not the Fuel SDK, but using SOAP API via Java?

Comment: The Fuel SDK is just a wrapper around the core SOAP and REST API operations.